# Showing if there is an image in a nested form with Carrier Wave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms

I'm doing a big nested form, where the user can upload an image for each nested form.
But I have a doubt. How can I show to the user, when he edit's the form, if there is already an image uploaded to each nested form? I thought of showing the image file name next to the file loader input, but i have no idea how to do that.

Here's my code:

**Model**

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :reference, :story_id, :image, :decisions_attributes

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@story) do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :chapters do |builder| %>
      <%= render "chapters_fields", f: builder %>
    <% end %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add chapters", f, :chapters, "chapters" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**Form Partial**

```
  <div class="chapter-fields">
      <h3>Chapter</h3>
      <p>
        <%= f.input :reference %>
        <%= f.input :content, as: :text, input_html: { rows: 10, style: 'width: 100%' } %>
        <%= f.input :image %>
        <%= f.image_url %>
      </p>
      <div>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :decisions do |builder| %>
          <%= render "decisions_fields", f: builder %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_fields "Add decisions", f, :decisions, "decisions" %>
      </div>
      <p><%= link_to_remove_fields "Remove chapter", f, "chapter" %></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the object behind a form builder variable via the `object` keyword.

```
if f.object.image.blank?
  "No current image"
else
  "Current image: #{f.object.image.url}"
end
```

**Note:** This only works if you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :chapters` in your `Story` model.

Comment: Thanks! But it worked only if i put f.object.image.url, when i try to print f.object.image.identifier, it returns nil.